# Update query in Microsoft Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I need to update multiple fields in a table.  If there is already data in one field I want to insert the data in the next field.
Example:
Date1  Date2  Date3

If there is a date in Date1 then populate Date2, if there is a date in Date 1 and Date2 then populate Date3 and so on.

Comment: Usually field names like Date1, Date2, Date3, etc., indicate that the true solution to the problem is to create a related table for the dates.  The updating scheme you are trying for makes it seem even more likely that you should do that.  If you post a question about the best table design for the problem you're modeling, you might get a more helpful response.

Answer (score 1):

```
Update Table
Set Date2 = IIF( Not IsNull( Date1 ), SomeDateValue, Date2 )
    , Date3 = IIF( Not IsNull( Date1 ) And Not IsNull( Date2 ), SomeDateValue, Date3 )
```

The question isn't clear regarding to what Date2 or Date3 should be set if other criteria is true. In this case, I presumed it was some value (`SomeDateValue`) which hasn't been mentioned.

Comment: Thomas the data I am collecting is receipt of checks.  I have the date of deposit, check number and amount.  The file that I bring in to match to my initial table is when the check has paid.  This file has the check number, amount and date paid.  Where I am running into my problem is when a check is a partial pay.  In other words the check was deposited on 3/28 for $100.00, it was paid on 3/29, but only 50.00 was paid and then on 3/31 the remainder was paid.  So I would need to be able to reflect the two dates and amounts.  3/29 for 50.00 and 3/31 for 50.00.

Comment: What does this table look like from a schema perspective? What does each row in the table represent: an invoice (with its payments)?

Comment: Thomas each row is receipt of a check

Comment: @Allen - If each row represents a single receipt of a check, why the three dates? To what do the checks apply: an invoice?

Comment: Thomas if I receive a check for 100.00 on 4/1/2010, I receive 50.00 partial payment on 4/2/2010 and a partial pay of 25.00 on 4/3/2010.There is an outstanding balance of 25.00.  I would like to update the table showing each date a partial payment was made and be able to run a query to show the outstanding balance.

Comment: @Allen - If you have three checks, you should store one *row* for each transaction (check). It sounds like you are trying to store payments toward an invoice in the invoices table. Instead, you should separate the two. One table for invoices and one table for checks. You can simplify your design if you force each check to apply to one and only one invoice. You would do that by creating a foreign key in the checks table that references the invoice to which it applies.